# Objective C Semi Readonly property

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, readonly

I want to declare a `public NSString property` in my `class` which acts as a `readonly property` outside my class but i can `assign` any value to it inside my class. How can i achieve this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to declare your property in the `.h` file like this

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSString *aString;

@end
```

but in your `.m` file you have to have

```
@interface MyClass () // your anonymous category

@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *aString;

@end

@implementation MyClass

@end
```

Externally the `aString` is `readonly` and internally you can set the value `(readwrite)`.

You are achieving it by implementing a `anonymous category also known as class extension in Objective-C`

Comment: @Injectios NO, question is about NSString and my answer contains a different explanation. IMPORTANT is the key word `private category` where questioner can read about further about it.

Comment: Your `NSString`s are not declared properly--they should be pointers.

Comment: The correct terminology is [class extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3).  "Anonymous category" is almost as good, but "private category" is wrong.  It's no more private than any other category.

Comment: @JeremyP thanks for notifying it to me. I've done the correction. But the term `private category` has been used widely in stackoverflow answers and in some advanced Objc books too.

Comment: The term "anonymous category" is still used while the official term Apple uses is: "class extension". From Apple docs: "A class extension bears some similarity to a category, but it can only be added to a class for which you have the source code at compile time."

Comment: @Goppinath What makes it sort of private (no property is really private), is putting the `@interface MyClass()` in the `.m` file but you can do the same with a named category.  Conversely, you can put a class extension in a header file just like a named category and its methods will then be visible everywhere it is imported.

Answer (score 3):

Define the property as `readonly` in the header and declare it `readWrite` in the implementation file in a `class extension`. The property will be readonly outside the classs implementation and read/write in the implementation.

```
// Interface file:
@interface Test : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *propertyString;
@end

// Implementation file:
@interface Test () // Class Extension
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString *propertyString;
@end

@implementation Test
@end
```

See: [Use Class Extensions to Hide Private Information](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3)

As @Amin Negm-Awad points out in an answer: the interface and class extension do not need to be in an interface or implementation file albeit this is the usual usage.

Answer (score 1):

In `.h` file add:

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly)NSString* property;
```

In `.m` file add:

```
@interface yourClass ()

@property(nonatomic,readwrite)NSString* property;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the property as readonly in your header file (interface), and as readwrite in your implementation file. That also allows you easily to make it weak / strong / copy.

Comment: The behavior with a partially defined readonly-property and a fully defined readwrite property changed in the recent time. No behavior is defined. It is best practice, to define all attributes of the property contained in the readwrite definition in the readonly definition, too.

Answer (score 0):

This might be quit obvious:

in your .h file declare property as `readonly`

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly, getter = isLoading) BOOL loading;
```

in your .m file declare property as `readwrite`

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite, getter = isLoading) BOOL loading;
```

This is an example, obviously you should create strong `NSString` property, and I assume compiler won't allow to set other value outside the class, but inside it will.

Answer (score -1):

Define the property as `readonly` in the header, and set it using the underscore syntax.

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *myString;

- (void)someMethodInYourDotMFile {
    _myString = YES;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Beside the existing answers that told you to define a readonly property and change it to a readwrite property, which is completely correct and the intended pattern (that is, what readwrite is for), I want to add an probably important information:

You put the readonly definition in the interface. (Not header!)

You put the readwrite definition in a class continuation. (Not implementation file)

One might say that this is the same, because interfaces reside in the header and class continuations reside in the implementation file. But this is only the usual case.

You can additionally put class continuations in a third file. Then something like a "friend class" can import it additionally and this "fried class" has write access. I do that very often, when developing frameworks.

MyClass.h: // public header, available for everybody

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (readonly, …) id property1; // Everyone can read it
@property (readonly, …) id property2; // Everyone can read it
- (void)method; // Everyone can use it
@end
```

MyClass_Package.h: // project header, available for framework classes, unavailable for the user of the framework

```
@interface MyClass()
@property (readwrite, …) id property1; // All classes inside the framework can write it
- (void)packageMethod;                 // All classes inside the framework can use it
@end
```

MyClass.m

```
@interface MyClass() // A second class extension inside .m
@property (readwrite, …) id property2; // Only MyClass can write it
- (void)privateMethod;                 // Only MyClass can use it
@end
```

Comment: Since this post is mainly pedantic it is [Class Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3) not `class continuation`.

Comment: 1. Nope. The post is not mainly pedantic, but newly introduces a pattern that is known in other programming languages as friendship. (And already known in Objective-C for ivars.) 2. Nope, sometimes it is called class continuation, sometime class extension. Class continuation is the better term, because categories are class extension, too. (And in a way subclasses.)

Comment: Regular categories are not class extensions. The two have different usages and capabilities. See the link in the preceding comment. Per Apple documentation: "Categories Add Methods to Existing Classes" while "Class Extensions Extend the Internal Implementation". "Unlike regular categories, a class extension can add its own properties and instance variables to a class."

Comment: I know what class extensions and categories (formally) are. But categories fulfill the meaning of the (informal) term "class extensions". They extend classes. Therefore I prefer the term class continuations for (formal) class extensions, because there is no danger of misunderstanding.